# How to send commands from PC to control a CC2540 microchip via bluetooth

Tags: c++, bluetooth

i have a PCB device with a [CC2540](http://www.ti.com/product/cc2540) microchip(also has a Blue tooth 4.0 module), i want to control this   PCB with my PC. So how shall i create program in my PC to send commands to this chip based on BLE 4.0? 
YOUR answers in details are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can write you own characteristics on CC2540 and flash it with your custom firmware.
Services and characteristics are parts of standard Bluetooth 4.0 and accepts 3 things:
- read
- write
- notify

So, you can use these characteristics to read, store or get notified from CC250 when a value is changed.